# aggregate data from 2 tables oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I have these data in 3 tables:

table 1: BU

| BU_CODE | ARCHIVE_FLG |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | Y |
| 1002 | Y |
| 1003 | Y |
| 1004 | N |
| 1005 | Y |

table 2: STG_ACCOUNT

| BU_CODE | ACCOUNT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | A0001 |
| 1001 | A0003 |
| 1002 | A0002 |

table 3: STG_CONTRACT

| BU_CODE | CONTRACT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1002 | C0001 |
| 1002 | C0002 |

These 2 queries work fine:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT
T2.BU_CODE, COUNT(T1.ACCOUNT_ID) AS COUNT_OF_ACCOUNT
FROM STG_ACCOUNT T1
FULL JOIN S_BU T2 ON T2.BU_CODE = T1.BU_CODE
WHERE T2.ARCHIVE_FLG = '1'
GROUP BY T2.BU_CODE
ORDER BY T2.BU_CODE;
```

| BU_CODE | COUNT_OF_ACCOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2 |
| 1002 | 1 |
| 1003 | 0 |
| 1005 | 0 |

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT
T2.BU_CODE, COUNT(T1.CONTRACT_ID) AS COUNT_OF_CONTRACT
FROM STG_CONTRACT T1
FULL JOIN S_BU T2 ON T2.BU_CODE = T1.BU_CODE
WHERE T2.ARCHIVE_FLG = '1'
GROUP BY T2.BU_CODE
ORDER BY T2.BU_CODE;
```

| BU_CODE | COUNT_OF_CONTRACT |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 0 |
| 1002 | 2 |
| 1003 | 0 |
| 1005 | 0 |

Now I would like to merge the result of these 2 queries to show a more elegant output:

| BU_CODE | COUNT_OF_ACCOUNT | COUNT_OF_CONTRACT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2 | 0 |
| 1002 | 1 | 2 |
| 1003 | 0 | 0 |
| 1005 | 0 | 0 |

What Oracle SQL function can help me?

Comment: Thanks for your formatted question, please have look at this link https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532039800346964883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be using `CTE` expressions

```
with x as 
( 
SELECT
T2.BU_CODE, COUNT(T1.ACCOUNT_ID) AS COUNT_OF_ACCOUNT
FROM STG_ACCOUNT T1
FULL JOIN S_BU T2 ON T2.BU_CODE = T1.BU_CODE
WHERE T2.ARCHIVE_FLG = '1'
GROUP BY T2.BU_CODE
ORDER BY T2.BU_CODE
), 
y as 
( 
SELECT
T2.BU_CODE, COUNT(T1.CONTRACT_ID) AS COUNT_OF_CONTRACT
FROM STG_CONTRACT T1
FULL JOIN S_BU T2 ON T2.BU_CODE = T1.BU_CODE
WHERE T2.ARCHIVE_FLG = '1'
GROUP BY T2.BU_CODE
ORDER BY T2.BU_CODE
) 
select x.bu_code , x.count_of_account, y.count_of_contract 
from x join y on x.bu_code=y.bu_code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join both tables.

```
SELECT
T1.BU_CODE AS BU_CODE, COUNT(DISTINCT T2.ACCOUNT_ID) AS COUNT_OF_ACCOUNT, COUNT(DISTINCT T3.CONTRACT_ID) AS COUNT_OF_CONTRACT
FROM S_BU T1
LEFT JOIN STG_ACCOUNT T2 ON T1.BU_CODE = T2.BU_CODE
LEFT JOIN STG_CONTRACT T3 ON T1.BU_CODE = T3.BU_CODE
WHERE T1.ARCHIVE_FLG = '1'
GROUP BY T1.BU_CODE
ORDER BY T1.BU_CODE;
```